# woocommerce_register_post action not firing

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I've followed [the instructions](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203182373-How-to-add-custom-fields-in-user-registration-on-the-My-Account-page) for adding extra fields to the WooCommerce registration form, and the fields show up and values are added to the database successfully.

However, I can't validate the new form field because the `woocommerce_register_post` action doesn't seem to fire.

I've tried replacing that action with `add_filter('woocommerce_registration_errors',…` and `add_filter('registration_errors',…` as well, but none seem to fire.

Anyone have any insight?

This is WP 4.2.4 and WC 2.4.3.

Code below for reference:

```
class Registration
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->actions();
    }

    public function actions()
    {
        add_action('show_user_profile', [$this, 'admin_customer_code']);
        add_action('edit_user_profile', [$this, 'admin_customer_code']);

        add_action('personal_options_update', [$this, 'save_admin_customer_code']);
        add_action('edit_user_profile_update', [$this, 'save_admin_customer_code']);

        add_action('woocommerce_register_form_start', [$this, 'registration_form']);
        add_action('woocommerce_register_post', [$this, 'registration_errors'], 10, 3);
        add_action('woocommerce_created_customer', [$this, 'user_register']);

        //add_filter('registration_errors', [$this, 'registration_errors'], 10, 3);
        //add_filter('woocommerce_registration_errors', [$this, 'registration_errors'], 10, 3);
    }

    public function admin_customer_code($user)
    {
        $customercode = esc_attr(get_the_author_meta('customer_code', $user->ID));

        $r = '<h3>Customer Code</h3>

            <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="customer_code">Customer Code</label></th>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="customer_code" id="customer_code" value="' . $customercode . '">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>';

        echo $r;
    }

    public function save_admin_customer_code($user_id)
    {
        update_user_meta($user_id, 'customer_code', sanitize_text_field($_POST['customer_code']));
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    public function registration_form()
    {
        $customercode = (! empty($_POST['customer_code'])) ? trim($_POST['customer_code']) : '';

        $r = '<p class="form-row form-row-wide">
            <label for="customer_code">' . __('Customer Code', 'textdomain') . ' <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="customer_code" id="customer_code" class="input" value="' . esc_attr(wp_unslash($customercode)) . '" size="25" />
        </p>';

        echo $r;
    }

    public function registration_errors($username, $email, $validation_errors)
    {
echo "registration_errors";
var_dump($_POST);
exit(); // Never happens :(
        if (empty($_POST['customer_code']) || ! empty($_POST['customer_code']) && trim($_POST['customer_code']) == '') {
            $validation_errors->add('customer_code_error', __('<strong>Error</strong>: Please provide your customer code.', 'textdomain'));
        }

        return $validation_errors;
    }

    public function user_register($user_id)
    {
        if (! empty($_POST['customer_code'])) {
            update_user_meta($user_id, 'customer_code', trim($_POST['customer_code']));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this with the [woocomm example](https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203182373) straight into the functions file, twentyfifteen theme, and even downgraded to WC2.1 and that action returns nothing. I can't figure out what's going on. Switched off all plugins too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`woocommerce_register_post` does fire. But only if both email and password are filled in.

So placing your extra form fields in before the form using `woocommerce_register_form_start` doesn't actually move those to the start for the validation.

Kind of annoying, it took me too long to figure out, but there you go.